# Logging in to main user turns off the mac

Tags: macos, encryption, recovery, malware

I am not a mac user, and honestly, I have no idea how to use one (besides the terminal). So, a friend asked if I could help them out with fixing their computer. She says the last thing she was on, was on some website with "free movies", and she mustt've been clicking something. We can get into recovery mode and we can go on the guest user, but not on the main user. Whenever you log in to the main user, it just shuts down.

Since I have a fair knowledge of Ubuntu, I thought I could just back up her files through a live USB (not store them on the live USB, but on an external hard drive) and reinstall OS X. I booted into the live USB, and there was no mounted hard drive, which was odd. I checked it, and figured it was encrypted, so I went on and installed libfvde on the live usb to see if I could hack the encrypted system open (had tried all kinds of other things before this), but I just could not do it.

So, what I want to do now is find out what is wrong, figure out if it can be fixed, and if not, back up the files and reinstall the OS. Thing is I don't know how to do it. Anything you guys can help with?

Comment: When it shuts down, does it appear to be a normal shutdown process? Or, does the machine just power off?

Comment: In a nutshell - boot to recovery mode and then look at terminal in the utilities menu. Tools like `gpt` and `df` and `diskutil cs list` or `diskutil list` should get you the lay of the storage land. You don't need a USB installer if recovery works so start there per [klanomath's answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/233594/5472)

Comment: I think you can do what you tried to do from a live USB from booting into [OS X recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314), which should support mounting the encrypted drive.

Comment: @tim.rohrer Screen turns black and computer turns off.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best thing you can do is creating a new admin user and inspecting the assaulted main user/the system.

---

Boot to Recovery Mode (hold <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> while booting).

Unlock and mount the main encrypted volume either with Disk Utility or Terminal:

```
#list all CoreStorage items
diskutil cs list
#unlock the locked Logical Volume (replace lvUUID by the UUID found above. Usually it's the last one listed and looks similar to this one: 21019876-ABA9-5678-1234-123453789012!)
diskutil cs unlockVolume lvUUID
```

Get the name of the main volume (usually it's the last one of the many):

```
df
```

The name of the encrypted main volume is also visible if you enter `diskutil cs list` again. Example:

```
    ...
    +-> Logical Volume 21019876-ABA9-5678-1234-123453789012
        ---------------------------------------------------
        Disk:                  disk16
        Status:                Online
        Size (Total):          1106191572992 B (1.1 TB)
        Conversion Progress:   -none-
        Revertible:            Yes (unlock and decryption required)
        LV Name:               Macintosh HD
  --->  Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
        Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

Change the working directory (here I assume the main volume name is "Macintosh HD"):

```
cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/var/db
```

List all files:

```
ls -laO
```

Remove the file .AppleSetupDone

```
rm .AppleSetupDone
```

Check if the file was deleted:

```
ls -laO
```

Reboot the Mac. After rebooting you will be asked to unlock the encrypted volume. Enter the password even if it is the one for the only configured user.

After booting has finished you will be asked to set-up your Mac. After configuring *locales* create a new admin user. Log-in as new admin user.

Now you may either back up the data of the infected main user. Or you can inspect LogIn items, launch agents of the user or system wide launch agents/daemons.

You may also install an anti-malware solution like [Anti-Malware for Mac](https://www.malwarebytes.org/antimalware/mac/) and check for an infection.

---

Report back if you can't find a culprit.

Comment: I am running into a problem at `cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/var/db`. I would expect it to move into the directory, just like normal, but nothing happens. I also think it's odd that where I am used to see `username@usergroup:~$` it says `-bash-3.2#`.

Comment: it appears to be Rasmus HDD (yes, with two d's). I wrote it in the terminal like this `cd /Volumes/Rasmus\ HDD/var/db`. Nothing happened.

Comment: @OHMYDEARPUFFINS Then try to cd to the directory successively: 1. `cd /Volumes` 2. `ls -laO` 3. `cd Ras..` 4. `ls -laO` 5. `cd var` etc. The O is a big Omaha. In step 3 you may use bash completion: Enter the first few letters of your main volume. Then hit the Tab key.

Comment: Ah, I see now, I wrote `ls -la0` (zero) instead of O (Omaha). It fixed the problems. Now I ran into other problems at `rm .AppleSetupdone`. It appears to be read-only, and can't get it removed. Anyway I can change its permissions?

Comment: @OHMYDEARPUFFINS What's your system version?

Comment: It says 10.10.3 via `sw_vers -productVersion`.

Comment: @OHMYDEARPUFFINS Though the file .AppleSetupDone seems to be read only you should be able to remove it. You are a root user! You may also use tab completion by entering `rm .AppleSe` after the e hit the Tab key. The correct name is .AppleSetupDone and **not** .AppleSetupdone!

Comment: Whatever I do, it just says `rm: .AppleSetupDone: Read-only file system`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37922/discussion-between-klanomath-and-oh-my-dear-puffins).

Comment: I see this was accepted as the answer, which is great! Can you tell us the cause and how it was fixed, specifically? Am I reading this that you basically re-ran the computer's setup script?

Comment: @tim.rohrer Though the answer is marked as accepted the issue is still there. Check the chat. Probably the CoreStorage volume was corrupted. The OP wanted to ping me if he is ready to continue solving the problem but he didn't until now.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get into the guest user, the problem does not lie within the system, so reinstalling it will not fix the problem.
Free movie sites (and other free sites) can sometimes trigger a virus or a bug that damages a Mac’s user files.
You would be better off if you started on an external hard disk, and then used Disk Utility (In Applications/Utilities) First Aide feature to “fix” the ahrd disk itself. 
It sounds as if the problem most likely is a disk error that will now allow the ahrd disk to mount properly. Disk Utility should be able to repair that.
You will know if Disk Utility finds an error (one that is listed in red under the Details arrow) and announces it has fixed it.
If disk utility does not repair the problem, the computer will need be taken to Apple or be looked at by a Mac Specialist or qualified consultant. There are many professional tools available to them to fix this problem.

Comment: If the disk wouldn't mount properly, logging in as guest wouldn't work either.

Comment: The OP said he could get in as guest, which is why I asked about the shutdown. I agree with part of the answer here that the OP, if he can get in as guest, might be able to su to the main user and then clean up nefarious log-in scripts, if that is what is happening.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I did try the disk utility thing (sorry, I tend to forget things as I write). Disk utility found no errors.